# Why can't I change the port in heroku postgres?

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I am using heroku and postgresql and python and trying to run my app locally.  In my .env file defines the port as "5432".  I use os.environ["PORT"] when I use the port number. I have also set my port in my main app to be 5432 using config:set.  But when I run the app it says:

```
"Is the server running on host "<hostname>" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5532?"
```

I have searched all over for my code and nowhere do I specify port 5532.  Where is it coming from?

Comment: In your `postgresql.conf` is the `port = [somenumber, probably 5532 in your case]` enabled (without `#` in front)?

Comment: Where is postgresql.conf found in a heroku app?

Comment: In your computer (as you said running locally) it is wherever your Postgres is installed. Or if you don't know then run `SHOW config_file;` in your `psql` client.

Comment: The database is on Heroku's cloud but the file was local.

Nevermind.  I think the port was not originally specified.  I specified it using heroku's config variables.